# Javascript or jquery to auto double click at specific location after single click

Tags: javascript, jquery

My website has a button that works after double click but it seems that users don't know that it works on double click, therefore they don't click it two times. Is there any javascript or jquery method that automatically double clicks at specific location after single is done ? Thanks for your answers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Triggering double click via jQuery or pure Javascript for a single click event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648264/triggering-double-click-via-jquery-or-pure-javascript-for-a-single-click-event)

Comment: possible duplicate of [highlight text on single click (javascript jquery html)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657937/highlight-text-on-single-click-javascript-jquery-html)

Comment: Why don't you listen for just the single click? A double click has a single click as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try to trigger `double click` within the `click` event.

```
$('selector').on('click', function () {
    $(this).trigger('dblclick');
});
```

*But I feel that if they double click it, then `dblclick` will be executed twice.* Instead try to show some messages like **"double click to get it worked"** inorder to show users.

From [@James Allardice's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7119911/1671639),

> it seems that there is going to be no reliable way to determine
>   whether the user intended a double click or two single clicks, but if
>   you want to try, you could perhaps use setTimeout in a click event
>   handler to see if another click occurs within a certain period of
>   time.

If you still need to have this, then go for [@Paolo Bergantino's hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1067484/1671639).

Comment: But i need double click at specific position. your answer will just click double at element id

Comment: @robinton how do I know about your HTML elements?  you haven't posted here.  In general `selector` represent id, class and elements.  Hence I posted a general approach :)

Answer (score 0):

You can Use:

```
$('#id/.class').click(function(){
$(this).dblclick(); 
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/539/)**

Comment: what happens if the you double click the button?  it show 2 times the alert.  which is not the exact behavior.

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan:you should be using other element like div instead of button.

Comment: No whatever element, when you trigger `dblclick` it will be executed twice.   check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YbPG5/1/ to get more understanding

Comment: I already found that hack and given as a reference in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20898288/1671639) ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#your_tag_id" ).click(function() {
   $( "#your_tag_id" ).dblclick();
});
```