# How to fire a double-click on click()

Tags: javascript, double-click

I am working with jaccordian and am wondering how JavaScript can fire a `dblclick()` when the user fires a single click. The trick is that it should only happen on specific classes.

Comment: simple question: what have you tried!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Triggering double click via jQuery or pure Javascript for a single click event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648264/triggering-double-click-via-jquery-or-pure-javascript-for-a-single-click-event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.dispatchEvent in most moddern browsers or just call .trigger - http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ in case you are using jQuery.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ |  onclick="$(this).trigger('dblclick')" specifically. Thanks again, guys!

Answer (score 0):

i cannot know exactly what you want BUT

if you want the double click to be on a different selector then you can simply do this

```
$('.your_selector').click(function() {
   $('.another_seletor').dblclick();
});
```

while if you want to fire the double click to the same selector then i you just cal `$('selector').click()` inside you `$('selector').click(function())`
here:

```
$('foo').click(function() {
   $('foo').click();
});
```

finally (i hope this is what you want), the pseudo code is like this:

```
$(many_selectors).click {
   //do a lot of code
   //but
   if(class of clicked element is foo)
   do a double click
}
```

this case it is the same like the second example but you only need to add the following:

```
var cls_of_elems_w_dbclk = ['class1','class2','class3'];
var class_of_clicked = $(this).attr("class");
if ($.inArray(class_of_clicked, cls_of_elems_w_dbclk) !== -1) {
   //then perform a another click
   $(this).click();
}
```